# Dealing with days of the week

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that counts through days of the week when given a number. I want to write this without using Arrays., or enum types, just methods How can I do this? I also want to be able to set a day of the week as starting point.

Thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args);
 {
  int sunday, monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday;
  int week;
  int day;

  System.out.println(" Day of the week is" + day);

  public void count()


  public void week()

  public void printday()

  public void nextday()

  public void previousday()
```

I'm not the best at this, but I figure practice makes perfect

Comment: use ArrayList instead of array

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli `I want to write this without using Arrays., or enum types`

Comment: Not using enums when enums are appropriate is at best a stupid constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do your trick, if i correctly understood your question :)

```
/**
 *
 * @param startingDay - day of the week starting point ( need to be between 0-6 )
 * @param noDays number of days to count
 * @return result Day of the week
 */
private static WeekDays getWeekDay(int startingDay, int noDays){
    int dayNr = noDays % 7;
    int finalDayNr = (startingDay + dayNr) % 7;
    return WeekDays.values()[finalDayNr];
}

private static enum WeekDays {
    SUNDAY,
    MONDAY,
    TUESDAY,
    WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY,
    FRIDAY,
    SATURDAY
}
```

And the version with no ENUM, however the Enum version is desirable... from any point of view you might think of.

```
/**
 *
 * @param startingDay
 *            - day of the week starting point ( need to be between 0-6 )
 * @param noDays
 *            number of days to count
 * @return result Day of the week
 */
private static String getWeekDay(int startingDay, int noDays) {
    int dayNr = noDays % 7;
    int finalDayNr = (startingDay + dayNr) % 7;
    return getDay(finalDayNr);
}

private static String getDay(int dayNr) {
    switch (dayNr) {
    case 0:
        return "SUNDAY";
    case 1:
        return "MONDAY";
    case 2:
        return "TUESDAY";
    case 3:
        return "WEDNESDAY";
    case 4:
        return "THURSDAY";
    case 5:
        return "FRIDAY";
    case 6:
        return "SATURDAY";
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong input. Day nr must be between 0-6.");
}
```

Usage sample ( for any of the two approach ):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getWeekDay(0, 15));
    System.out.println(getWeekDay(1, 15));
    System.out.println(getWeekDay(5, 3));
}
```

Comment: He does not want enums nor arrays, you are using both

Comment: are you kidding me ? :)

Comment: Nope, that's why I would not answer such a question. Bad questions lead to bad answers, because we should basically just tell him that he should not try it without enums, even if it is possible

Comment: when i read the question i was thinking he doesn't want to keep track of endless array with { number, weekOfDay } :D never tought it refered to the actual days of the week. However, no matter the request, you should give the man what he wants, right ?

Comment: If someone asks you how to go from London to Los Angeles in train, will you explain them how to build a submarine train or will you give them the direction to the airport ?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like homework, but if you are not going to use arrays of days, I guess you can use a `switch` statement with the days of the week.

This particular sample iterates from day 3 (0 being Monday) to day 14 included.

```
for (int i = 3; i < 15; i++) {
    String s = null;
    switch (i % 7) {
        case 0: s = "Monday"; break;
        case 1: s = "Tuesday"; break;
        case 2: s = "Wednesday"; break;
        case 3: s = "Thursday"; break;
        case 4: s = "Friday"; break;
        case 5: s = "Saturday"; break;
        case 6: s = "Sunday"; break;
    }
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int day = 1;

    System.out.println(isWeek(day));
    printday(day);

}

public static boolean isWeek(int day) {
    // Sunday or Saturday
    if (day == 1 || day == 7) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public static void printday(int day) {
    switch (day) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Sunday");
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Monday");
        break;
    // Until Saturday

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Bad code but without arrays or enums someting like that ?